# Google Map Click Event Issue with Kohana PHP

Tags: google-maps, kohana

So this gets auto generated through the controller and I think I'm just overlooking something but the output is just like this

---

```
google.load("maps", "2.x", {"language" : "en"});
function initialize() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        // Initialize the GMap
        var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.addControl(new google.maps.SmallMapControl());
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(30.226632, -97.935056), 10, G_NORMAL_MAP);


    // Build custom marker icons
    var tinyIcon = new google.maps.Icon();
    tinyIcon.image = "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png";
    tinyIcon.shadow = "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png";
    tinyIcon.iconSize = new google.maps.Size(12,20);
    tinyIcon.shadowSize = new google.maps.Size(22,20);
    tinyIcon.iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(6,20);
    tinyIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new google.maps.Point(5,1);

    // Show map points
    var m1 = new google.maps.Marker(new google.maps.LatLng(35.2602340, -93.7939480), {icon:tinyIcon,bouncy:1});
    google.maps.Event.addListener(m1, "click", function()
    {
        m1.openInfoWindowHtml(
            '1<br />test,TX'
        );
    });
    map.addOverlay(m1);
    var m2 = new google.maps.Marker(new google.maps.LatLng(35.2810510, -93.8246510), {icon:tinyIcon,bouncy:1});
    google.maps.Event.addListener(m2, "click", function()
    {
        m2.openInfoWindowHtml(
            'test<br />test,Texas'
        );
    });
    map.addOverlay(m2);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

---

So when i go to use a trigger event

google.maps.event.trigger(markers[m3], 'click');

Nothing happens, and I cant figure out the correct trigger to make it do so...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code sample you posted there is no markers[m3] defined, wouldn't you need to use google.maps.event.trigger(m2, 'click'); ? (m3 isn't defined at all in that code sample)